# Deleting columns from a csv if it contains a certain value

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv from which I want to drop the columns which has only '-' values in it. These are the columns I want to drop:

[image]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html) for test not `-` value with [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for test if not exist in all rows anf filter by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) - first `:` means al rows and second is mask for filter columns:

```
df = df.loc[:, df.ne('-').all()]
```